# Passing abstract object by value weirdness in clang++

Tags: c++

why does clang++ 3.6 compile the follwing code (g++ doesn't)?

```
class Abc
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual ~Abc() {}
};

// is correctly rejected
// void bar(Abc o)
// {
// }

class B
{
    void bar(Abc o) // should also be rejected
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
}
```

I am using clang 3.6 and gcc 4.9.2.

Why is the free function (correctly) rejected and the member function not?

Any hints? A Bug in clang?

If I modify the above to:

```
class Abc
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual ~Abc() {}
};
class Impl : public Abc {
public:
    void foo() const {}
};
class B
{
public:
    void bar(Abc o)
    {
        o.foo();
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    Impl i;
    b.bar(i);
}
```

I get an

main.cc:16: undefined reference to `Abc::foo() const'

linker error.

So the question is: why at all allows clang++ to compile this wrong code?
I would say that is a heavy bug!

Comment: I guess should rejected,gcc is right,the reason maybe is object slicing.If changeAbc to Abc& both ok.

Comment: What happens if you initialise a `B` object? If that still works, can you take a function pointer to `B::bar`?

Comment: A guess, nothing more. I see that some compiler checks the syntax of unused inlined function or unused template function, someone doesn't.

Well, bar(Abc) is an inlined private function of B with empty implementation never referenced. bar() is private so no inherithed class cans refer to it. No global pointer should be obtained, or at least no one is asking for it.

Could you try to make it public? call the function somewhere? provide an not inline and not empty implementation?

Comment: I edited the above to be more clear in what I mean: the above code is wrong and I want clang++ to reject it (and not the linker).

Answer (score 1):

As N4296 10.4 [class.abstract]
says:

> An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type, as a function
>   return type, or as the type of an explicit conversion. Pointers and
>   references to an abstract class can be declared.

```
[ Example:
shape x;//  error: object of abstract class
shape* p;// OK
shape f();// error
void g(shape);// error
shape& h(shape&);//OK
— end example ]
```

So gcc follow the standard.

Why cannot declare parameter to be of abstract type? Suppose when a pass subclass object to bar,object slicing happen,oh,an object that has a pure virtual function...This is a contradiction.That maybe the reason.

### EDIT:

Why clang pass it,it is clang compiler issue.

Comment: I know that one cannot pass an ABC by value: I want the compiler to reject that code! g++ is clearly right, and I would say clang++ has a heavy bug.

Comment: @wimalopaan Maybe you are right,I guess,maybe some optimization mechanism lead to ignore the check.I will wait other answer with you.

Comment: Just checked on clang-dev ... they said, that there are issues with ABCs. So, yes, it seems to be a bug in clang. Lets wait till it gets fixed.